# Formulas for dividing two columns

Tags: excel

I have a large file in which I want to divide every cell Ax by Bx and have the answer be placed in Cx, where x is a variable for the row. I'd have three columns of equal size after the operation. What kind of command would I use to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working for you? Please show some individual effort :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first row that you need the division, in Cx, type the following:

```
=A2/B2
```

Assuming that you are starting on row 2. Then you can either double-clicking on the bottom-right corner of the *selected* cell C2 (you should see a bold `+`) or copy and paste cell C2 over the entire range that you wish to have the division.